# SF story/novel about searching for the creator of a collage. I thought it was by William Gibson but can't find it, Perhaps another author

Tags: story-identification

There was a story about a valuable and very stunning collage. I forgot exactly why it was so sought after but it falls into someone's hands and they are desperately trying to find out who created it. I think it ends by finding the creators who, as I remember, were twins, perhaps living in a secluded artist's commune in Japan. Thought it was in story by William Gibson but can't find anything.

Comment: In [Count Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Zero), William Gibson has a thread where a rich man seeks the source of boxes with artistically arranged objects inside them - sort of 3D collages.  However, the source turns out to be an AI in orbit, not twins in Japan.

Comment: It's kind of interesting in that William Gibson was writing about this almost 50 years ago and now we have AI creating art.  Hmmm.  What next?

Answer (score 18):

There are a lot of similarities here with Gibson's [*Pattern Recognition*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?23596) where Cayce Pollard is tasked with tracking down a video assembled from clips.

She does end up in Tokyo, but the creators are in Moscow.  Or really the creator, Nora, who suffered brain damage and communicates by creating the clips.  Her twin sister Stella is the one that Cayce meets and talks to.

Comment: Yes, that's very familiar also, I think perhaps I was conflating one story with the other because the brain damaged twin is very familiar.  Thanks! Might have to re-read that trilogy.

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I thought of when I saw the description.

Comment: As for the "collage" part - I believe that something about the location of each clip relative to the others could be deduced, and the map of the space in which all the footage was happening revealed some specific shape when it was assembled near the end of the book.